# Programmatically add UIButton to custom ViewController with storyboard in place

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I've successfully implemented walkthrough screens by following [AppCoda's Create UIPageViewController Using Storyboard tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/). At the end of the example a UIPageControl is created in code and now I'm trying to add a UIButton the same way, programmatically.

The button appears if added via storyboard but otherwise none of these have worked for me when (individually) added to my `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
// [self.view addSubview:button];
// [self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
// [self.view insertSubview:button atIndex:0];
// [self.view insertSubview:button atIndex:[self.view subviews].count + 1];
// [self.view insertSubview:button aboveSubview:self.view];
// [self initButton:button];
```

There's got to be something relatively simple that I'm missing. Should I just stick to Android?

Comment: Just uncomment [self.view addSubview:button]; line and it should work.

Comment: Each of those lines is what I've already tried individually, and then commented out as they didn't work. Sorry if I confused anyone.

Comment: It should work maybe you have some other view added on top of self.view which hover over your button.

Comment: That was it. Later in my UIViewController I was adding a UIPageViewController which hid the button. Thanks for taking a look, I'll accept as correct if you want to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uncomment `[self.view addSubview:button];` line and it should work. 
If it doesn't work I believe you have some other view added on top of self.view which hover over your button.